# how to install the Tizen Api in my application

Tags: javascript, tizen

In tizen tv, iam not able to exit the application can share related documentation ,i need in javascript
how install tizen api in the my project and "tizenhwkey" is not working  i have add eventListener but is not working .....

Comment: would you check this page? https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/quick-start-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

[tizenhwkey](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.ui.practices/html/web/tau/event_handling_w.htm) is a feature supported on mobile and wearable devices and it is related to hardware keys provided by the device.

TVs use remote controller for navigation over application, so the event handling is slightly different. To control events, Tizen Studio (for tv profile) adds by default below snippet:

```
// add eventListener for keydown
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode){
    case 37: //LEFT arrow
        break;
    case 38: //UP arrow
        break;
    case 39: //RIGHT arrow
        break;
    case 40: //DOWN arrow
        break;
    case 13: //OK button
        break;
    case 10009: //RETURN button
        tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Key code : ' + e.keyCode);
        break;
    }
});
```

which is a nice starting point for adding own event handling, and also it already supports exiting application with 'Return' button, which should resolve your problem.

Comment: tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
in console it is showing , tizen is not defined